# How to leaks memory management when having a lot of image Swift?

Tags: swift, memory-management

When I used CollectionView and cell I add lots of images. When I scroll many cell and many images, after a while the memory leaks and have big size. To show the image on a cell I used library image ImageSlideshow that have 5 images in one cell and can swap left and swap right. But, when I scroll many cells the memory has a big size and crash. how can we solve this problem?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.myIndexPath = indexPath

        let data = self.jsonData[indexPath.row]
        let slidershow = ImageSlideshow()
        slidershow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        slidershow.pageControl.bounds = CGRect(x: (-1)*(self.view.bounds.width/2-50), y: 10, width: 10, height: 10)
        slidershow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        slidershow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        slidershow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        slidershow.slideshowInterval = 0
        // optional way to show activity indicator during image load (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
        slidershow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
        slidershow.currentPageChanged = { page in
                                         print("current page:", page)
                                        }

        if (data.imagesKingfiser?.count)!>0 {
            if "\(String(describing: data.imagesKingfiser?[0].url))" == "Optional(http://test.cambodianmatch.com/theareak.png)"{
                slidershow.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "no_image_available")!)])
            }else{
                slidershow.setImageInputs(data.imagesKingfiser!)
            }
        }
        else {
            slidershow.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "no_image_available")!)])
        }

        cell.id = data.id
        cell.index = indexPath.row
        cell.friendMemberShipStatus = data.memberShipStatus
        cell.address = data.age! + ", " + data.city! + ", " + data.country!
        cell.graphRadius.counter = data.matchNumber!
        cell.number = Double(indexPath.row)
        cell.addressLabel.text = data.age! + ", " + data.city! + ", " + data.country!
        cell.usernameLabel.text = data.userName
        cell.selectFavorite = data.favorite!
        cell.numberPersonView.text = "\(String(describing: data.matchNumber!))%"
        cell.addSliderView(slider: slidershow)

        //check favorite
        if data.favorite == 1 {
            cell.favoriteLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0xec265a)
        }else{
            cell.favoriteLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0x929292)
        }

        cell.favorite = data.favorite!

        //check membership
        if data.memberShipStatus == 1 {
            cell.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.addressLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

            cell.eliteLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.elitImageVIew.isHidden = false
            cell.heightEliteConstraint.constant = 22
            cell.numberPersonView.textColor = UIColor.white
        }else {
            cell.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex:0x097FAB)
            cell.addressLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex:0x097FAB)
            cell.numberPersonView.textColor = UIColor(hex:0x097FAB)
            cell.heightEliteConstraint.constant = 0
            cell.eliteLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.elitImageVIew.isHidden = true
        }
        //check Online
        cell.isActive = data.onlineStatus
        if data.onlineStatus == 1 {
            cell.activeLabel.isHidden = false
        }else{
            cell.activeLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Don't you dequeuing your cells?

Comment: Are you really Memory Leak issue, or are you juste consuming too much memory? That's two different problems. For instance, your code could be leak free, but it you always shows images of 100Mo in your cells rendering them into a 100*100 imageView, you'll have a memory warning, but not a leak. Please show your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: now i upload code ready do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Use SDWEBImage for caching, reuse cells , hopefully you have ARC enabled.